# How to implement IBM MQ with Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-mq

How to implement IBM MQ with Nodejs?

Hello everyone, I need to implement a script that from nodejs can connect ibm qm this remotely, I have seen several documentation on the internet and seen for repository but it is not very clear to me, I could better clarify

this is the information that I have consulted:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58066992/config-connection-node-js-app-with-ibm-mq?rq=1)
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/blob/master/samples/README.md)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an npm library that you can use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmmq

which has samples in its GitHub home repository -
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs

Further usage samples are available in the IBM MQ pattern samples repository - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/Node.js

The patterns repository also has examples on how to connect over REST using the `axios` npm module - https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/blob/master/serverless/openwhisk/mq-package/src/utillib/mqrestapi.js